# react-router and typescript "match" issue in Link to routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

As I'm new to both react and typescript I've read several articles about how to get the "match" property from react-router working using typescript and I haven't been able to successfully do it. I have no parameters I am passing, I just want to be able to use the match.url of react-router.

So the examples I am seeing is that the  field in the login.tsx file should use {match.url}.  I tried the react 4 router demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nn8x24vm60?from-embed where they used {`${match.url}/register`} but that didn't work either.  Then I saw some posts where people said you had to declare an interface but it was split between RouteComponent and Route and most were dealing with parameters.  Basically all I want it to do is when I click the link to switch to the register route(it's in register.tsx - not shown here as it's a simple file with just a header on it).

Currently its throwing the following eror:

```
    "Error  TS2739  (TS) Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type
 'Readonly<MyProps & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>>': register, history, location, match"
```

Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

app.tsx file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './home';
import { Register } from './register';
import { NavBar } from './navbar';

export class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <NavBar/>            
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />               
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));

home.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Login } from './login';
import { Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';

const jumboStyle = {
    background: 'lightgray',
    height: '20%',
    width: '40%',
    margin: 'auto'
};


export class Home extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                < Jumbotron style={jumboStyle}>
                    <h1>Welcome to the new League!</h1>
                    <h4>Please log in with your username and password to continue</h4>
                    <Login />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </Jumbotron>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

login.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Link, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Register } from './register';

interface IState {
    [key: string]: any; // or the type of your input
} 

interface MyProps {
    register: Register
}
const styles = {
    background: 'lightblue'
};

export class Login extends React.Component<MyProps & RouteComponentProps, IState> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            authorized: false

        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }


    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        });
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
      //we are goingto submit the form to the database
        event.prevent.default();
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <TextField
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        label="UserName"
                        helperText="Enter your Username"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        required={true}
                        style={styles}
                    />

                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        helperText="Enter your password"
                        label="Password"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        required={true}
                        style={styles}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br/>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        value="Submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"

                    >Submit</Button>   
                    <br />
                    <br/>
                    <Alert variant="info">
                        <Alert.Heading>Don't Have An Account Setup?</Alert.Heading>
                        <div>
                            <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/register`}>Register Here</Link>
                        </div>
                    </Alert>
                </form>


            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `react-router` properties (such as `match`) are only automatically injected into the component rendered by a route (`Home` in this case). You can add them to your component using the `withRouter` wrapper. You then have to use the wrapped component instead of the internal one.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

...

class LoginInternal extends React.Component<MyProps & RouteComponentProps, IState> {

...

export const Login = withRouter(LoginInternal);
```

Comment: This looks like it is going to work but I am having 2 issues: 1) this.props.match.url is "/" and then I get a 404 Error when I click the link and it says it cannot find register even though I have it imported and exported properly.

Comment: It looks like you actually don't even need the current url in this case, since you are going to an absolute url. Try just using `<Link to="/register">`

Comment: Still get the same issue...it shows /register in the url in the address bar but I get a 404 not found error

Comment: I feel like an idiot...I had to put exact on the "/" path because it was always going to that first...once I did that it worked the first time.  Didn't even need to do any of this, the way I had it worked fine and I just put "/register" in the Link to instead of using "match"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props from Home component to Login component.

```
<Login match={this.props.match}/>
```

It should work.